# When should i send an Interface to a Ctor?

Tags: c#

Can you give and example when should I send an interface to a Ctor?
Let say if I want to force a class to use a specific behavior?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You pass an interface to a constructor for the same reasons you pass an interface to any method. For example, if your constructor takes a list of objects, you may accept an IList rather than a List. This is saying that the constructor accepts any option that looks and behaves like a list rather than requiring an actual list, making it more generic.

Comment: A similar example is  `ICollection`, all lists and arrays inherits from it and it provides the `Count` property. So if the method(or constructor) needs that property only, he might want a `ICollection` rather than an actual `List<T>` or `T[]` to be more flexible.

Answer (score 2):

This kind of behavior is traditionally seen in the context of the [decorator pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decorator_pattern), when you wish to be able to change the behavior of different instances of a class by passing different "decorators" as parameters at creation time (or later). Example:

```
interface ISerializer 
{
    void Serialize(object obj);
}

class BinarySerializer : ISerializer
{
    public void Serialize(object obj) 
    {
        // serialize obj as binary stream
    }
}


class XMLSerializer : ISerializer
{
    public void Serialize(object obj) 
    {
        // serialize obj as XML
    }
}

// ...

class PersistanceManager
{
    private ISerializer serializer;

    public PersistanceManager(ISerializer serializer)
    {
        this.serializer = serializer;
    }

    public void Persist(object[] objects) 
    {
         foreach(object obj in objects)
         {
              serializer.Serialize(obj);
         }
    }
}
```

Now I can inject different behaviors at runtime:

```
PersistanceManager manager1 = new PersistanceManager(new BinarySerializer());
PersistanceManager manager2 = new PersistanceManager(new XMLSerializer());
```

Answer (score 2):

I think what you really want to ask and do is 'Why would I have a constructor taking an object which implements specific interface'.

This behavior allows you to `inject` different type of objects into the object that is about to be created. You may easily change for example where data is about to be written (files, network, database).

Injecting is related to [Depency Injection pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_injection)

Answer (score 1):

You can do this if you want to separate your dependencies from your class. Instead of creating an instance if another class in your custom class you inject that dependency from outside your custom class via an interface.

This dependency injection can be done by custom coffee that you write yourself, or you can make use of a dependency container. Some of the popular ones for this in the .NET world are Unity, Ninject or Autofac.